# Why am i getting NETWORK ERROR for all my HTTPS request in REACT NATIVE?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

I am having this issue, all request https to my express server from React native returns Network error(on android) but i can do from postman and from another projects in react or angular it works fine. React native version :0.62.2, axios version 0.19.2, if i deploy my server in http and not https it works fine and SSL certificate are ok

Comment: try "request" package and see if it's "axios" problem or not

Comment: i tryed fetch and problem still exist

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Android (9+) you have to specify a whitelist of non-HTTPS host names that your app can access. Otherwise trying to access such host names will result in a network error.

Create the following file if does not exist - `android/app/src/debug/react_native_config.xml`.

The contents should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">192.168.0.1</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">YOUR_SERVER_IP</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Make sure the server you're trying to access is listed here and then recompile and reinstall the application on your device.

Comment: but my server is running in HTTPS